# How to set expiry time to shortened URLs

Tags: url-shortener, bit.ly, google-url-shortener, tinyurl

I searched the web, which told me that the shortened URLs we get from different URL shortener websites are valid forever. But I want to make such a shortened URL with the help of those sites, which will be expired after some specific time, say 80 hours.

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this. It will be having expiry time. Once URL is expired, it will redirect to configured URL
http://once.ly/index.html

Comment: Please write a textual answer and not a (temporary) link to an answer.

Answer (score -1):

As I far as I know there is a service called [pqn.PW](http://www.pqn.pw) that does something similar. The only difference is the time period. Your link can last 1 hour, 1 day, 1 month or 1 year.

Comment: 404 not available anymore